# Intellij Idea - Attach to existing VCS

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I have a project on Github that I pulled down to my new computer and opened the project in Intellij Idea and on my other computer I set up the project with Github through Intellij so it is already set up to commit and push changes to my repository. But with my computer I am not sure who to attach Idea to the existing Git repository without screwing anything up. I couldn't find the process online but its possible I just missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the project in IntelliJ, it will detect the `.git` folder inside and offer you to "attach" to it.

Or, you can open your settings, enter the search string "version control". Select the **Version Control** menu, and on the right side you'll see a pane titled **Directory**, where normally you'd see a list of directories mapped to a VCS. At the bottom of this pane there is a `+` button, click on it to add a directory.

I've always done it the first way though. IntelliJ usually adds the directory automatically, or offers you to add it in a small pop-up box in the top-right corner.

Comment: I never saw the offer to "attach" popup or anything like that but when I followed your instructions into the menu, under the Directoy pane, it had that offer. Worked great, thanks!